# How to move modal dialog

Tags: python, pyqt

The code below creates `QMainWindow`. Right clicking within its frame calls `up` function.
This function makes `self.modal` modal `QDialog` unhidden.
Question: why self.modal QDialog is not moving to QCusrsor position as it is requested by `self.modal.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())` line inside of scope of 'up()' function?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        mainWidget=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)
        frame=QtGui.QFrame()
        frame.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        frame.connect(frame, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.up)
        mainLayout.addWidget(frame)

        self.modal=QtGui.QDialog()
        self.modal.setModal(True)

    def up(self, QPos):
        print 'up  QPos: %s  QCursor: %s'%( QPos, QtGui.QCursor.pos() )
        self.modal.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.modal.show()

window=AppWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QCursor.pos()` returns global screen coordinates.  I believe `QDialog.mov()` expects widget coordinates, so you have to translate with `self.modal.move(QWidget.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos()))`

Comment: `self.modal.move(self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos()))` this didn't work

Comment: what does your print statement give you?